# Converting a Phone Number to Letters (C#)

Tags: c#, phone-number

So for this C# class I have to have the user input a 7 digit phone number into the console. Each number is stored as a different character. Then each character is changed to a letter. There is no logic behind the letters the numbers are changed to. (I really don't see the point of this assignment, which might be contributing to my coder's block.) Here's what the assignment says.

Your mission: A prepaid phone service needs a program that converts alphanumeric keyboard input into a phone number. The user will input eight characters and the program will output either an error message or the translated seven-digit phone number. The input may contain digits, letters, or both. Letters can be uppercase or lowercase.

Method of Coding:

- Main(): Declares seven character variables and passes these to the following methods by reference:

  - ProcessInput(): gets user input and performs the conversion

    - ShowResults(): displays the results

      - GetInput(): Gets seven characters from the user and stores them into the seven variables Main() has passed by reference.
      - ProcessInput(): Calls ToDigit() for each, passing each character variable by reference, and returns one of these codes to Main() by value:
        o 0 if there were no input errors
        o -1 if there were input errors"

The program will perform the conversion per a standard telephone keypad layout.

Basically, 2 s A,B,C
3 is D,E,F
Etc and then D, E, F is 3 and so on.

Right now I have nothing done except for an input, but it's not stored as characters, just a string. I really hate this assignment because we just did two assignments with Cases and If statements, it just seems redundant to me.

```
Console.WriteLine("Write a Phone Number that consists of Seven Numbers.");
string Number = Console.ReadLine();

if (Number.Length != 7)
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered a phone number that is too long.");

Console.WriteLine("You have entered: {0}", Number);
Console.ReadLine();
```

So my real question is: How do I store the input number as a character and then define those characters with case statements?

Comment: So what is your question? BTW please tag your question `homework`

Comment: How do I store the input number as a character and then define those characters with case statements?

Comment: You can use the [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) Method to create your character array

Comment: @MarkHall or he could just index the string `Number[0]` is perfectly valid.

Comment: We're not allowed to use Arrays :/ That's probably what makes it so frustrating.

Comment: @user1580598 You will need to get your string broken down into characters somehow, what Scott Chamberlain mentions should be viable.

Comment: I think you are understanding the assignment backwards.  You are to take alphanumeric input and convert to a phone number.  Your question title seems to indicate the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sorry for not responding to this or picking a right answer, I eventually figured it out on my own. The reason I was having so much trouble was because I thought I was suppose to create several outputs for 1(800)384-2347 and convert the last 4 numbers into various letters that might make sense. But it was just a simple case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a Dictionary class if it has not been covered in class, you will likely get a bad grade on the assignment as this homework is to be solved using the tools you learned in class.

There are two ways you could solve this.

1. Make a `switch` statement for every letter or number a person could enter. This will likely get you a bad grade if you make a `case` for every letter of the alphabet and enter it's corresponding number, but if you use some of the features of `case` statements like "fall through" (no link, I leave it to you to research what that is) you will likely get a good grade.
2. This can also be done with `if` statements, and just like point 1, if you make a `if` for every entry you will get a bad grade, but if you can figure out how to solve `A, B, C, and 1` with one `if` you may get a good grade.

---

I will give you the answer for how to get each letter individually because I don't think that is the purpous of the lesson, the easist way is to do it with a foreach statement.

```
string finalNumber = "";
foreach(char digit in Number)
{
  finalNumber += ProcessDigit(digit);
}
Console.WriteLine(finalNumber);

//Elsewhere
char ProcessDigit(char digit)
{
     char newDigit;

     //change digit to whatever you needed to turn it in to and store it in newDigit;

     return newDigit;
}
```

Also another freebee, do a [ToUpperInvariant()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant) on the string before you feed it in to the foreach and you only need to check capital letters.

Comment: So how exactly do I make it so the entered numbers can be ran across the switch/if statements?

Comment: Updated with the answer as I don't think it is the intent of the homework as you described it is to test you on `foreach` statements.

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to use a foreach statement either :'[

Comment: I updated the question with a sort of "guide" we're suppose to be using.

Comment: If you can't use foreach then you must use a `for` with the indexing I showed in the comment in the original question, however this is the end of the handholding I will do and you will need to figure the rest of the problem out yourself. "Give a man a fish..."

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, some steps you should do:

1. Create a **map** of letters to numbers as corresponds to the keypad on the telephone
2. Loop through each character of the entered string:

   1. If its a number (an integer), then look it up in the letter > number mapping, print the character.
   2. If its a letter, then look up the same table, and print the corresponding number.
   3. If it doesn't match the two conditions, print an error message.

Comment: How do I map the letters and numbers though? 

case = 2
case = 'A'
case = 'B'
case = 'C'
result = '2'

Comment: Being they just learned IF and CASE statements he is likely expected not to use a dictionary but one of the above mention tools.

Comment: Yes, you can use a very long `CASE` statement, or you can use a Dictionary (see my previous comment), or you can use a bunch of `if`s

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I thought this was Java too and I first linked to Map, then realized its C#

Comment: I believe that is what the instructor is expecting.

Comment: God, Dictionary would be so easy! I'm going to use it to test it out anyways, just for a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a dictionary that maps all possible input characters to your desired output. Upon input you replace the character based on the dictionary.

Comment: Being they just learned IF and CASE statements he is likely expected not to use a dictionary but one of the above mention tools.

Comment: Yeah, the code is suppose to be composed of If and Case statements. :/

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("ABC", 2);
        dict.Add("CDE", 3);
        dict.Add("FGH", 4);
        dict.Add("JKL", 5);

        string Numbers = "BDJ";
        string myints = "";
        foreach (char c in Numbers)
            myints += dict.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Key.Contains(c)).Value.ToString();
//the output : "235"
```